# Coroutine gets stuck at random times?

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, coroutine

The question says it all, I have a Coroutine that I am using to create some spinning animation. The problem is that it suddenly stops randomly (at different times). I don't know what might be causing this as it works most of the times (8 times out of 10) on PC. I also built the game and tried it on an android phone but it only works (3 times out of 10). Any idea what might be causing this?

This is my Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpinWheelScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public CanvasGroup spinWheelCanvas;

    public GameObject[] rewards;
    public GameObject[] pointerDir;
    public GameObject[] ringDir;
    public GameObject pointer;
    public GameObject ring;

    private Quaternion pointerTargetRotation;
    private Quaternion ringTargetRotation;

    private bool spinIsEnabled = false;
    private bool isSpinning = false;
    private bool lastSpin = false;
    private bool animationIsEnabled = false;

    private float time;
    private float pSpeed;
    private float rSpeed;
    private float pointerRotateFloat;
    private float ringRotateFloat;

    private int rewardEnabler = 0;
    private int randomReward;
    private int pRandomDir;
    private int rRandomDir;
    private int plastRandomDir = 0;
    private int rlastRandomDir = 0;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (spinIsEnabled == false)
        {
            // Do Nothing
        }

        else if (spinIsEnabled == true && isSpinning == false)
        {
            // Select reward
            if (rewardEnabler == 0)
            {
                RewardSelector();
                rewardEnabler = 1;
            }

            StartCoroutine(Spin());
        }

        if (lastSpin == true)
        {
            Debug.Log(randomReward);

            pointerRotateFloat = ((360 - (randomReward * 60)) - 30);
            ringRotateFloat = ((360 - (randomReward * 60)) - 30);

            if (pointerRotateFloat > ringRotateFloat)
            {
                pSpeed = (pointerRotateFloat);
                rSpeed = (pointerRotateFloat / ringRotateFloat) * (ringRotateFloat);
            }
            else
            {
                rSpeed = (ringRotateFloat);
                pSpeed = (ringRotateFloat / pointerRotateFloat) * (pointerRotateFloat);
            }

            Quaternion pointerTargetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, pointerRotateFloat));
            pointer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(pointer.transform.rotation, pointerTargetRotation, pSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Quaternion ringTargetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, ringRotateFloat));
            ring.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(ring.transform.rotation, ringTargetRotation, rSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            if ((pointer.transform.rotation == pointerTargetRotation) && (ring.transform.rotation == ringTargetRotation))
            {
                lastSpin = false;
                isSpinning = false;
                spinIsEnabled = false;
                animationIsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Spin()
    {
        isSpinning = true;
        pSpeed = 0;
        rSpeed = 0;
        time = 0;

        while (time < 15)
        {
            pRandomDir = PointerRandomDirection();    // Function to pick a random number.
            rRandomDir = RingRandomDirection();    // Function to pick a random number.

            for (;;)
            {
                pointerRotateFloat = (((pRandomDir + 1) * 60) - 30) - pointer.transform.rotation.z;
                ringRotateFloat = (((rRandomDir + 1) * 60) - 30) - ring.transform.rotation.z;

                if (pointerRotateFloat > ringRotateFloat)
                {
                    pSpeed = (pointerRotateFloat);
                    rSpeed = (pointerRotateFloat / ringRotateFloat) * (ringRotateFloat);
                }
                else
                {
                    rSpeed = (ringRotateFloat);
                    pSpeed = (ringRotateFloat / pointerRotateFloat) * (pointerRotateFloat);
                }

                pointerTargetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, pointerRotateFloat));
                pointer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(pointer.transform.rotation, pointerTargetRotation, pSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                ringTargetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, ringRotateFloat));
                ring.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(ring.transform.rotation, ringTargetRotation, rSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

                Debug.Log("Before the if");

                if ((pointer.transform.rotation == pointerTargetRotation) && (ring.transform.rotation == ringTargetRotation))
                    break;

                yield return null;
            }

            time++;
        }

        lastSpin = true;
    }

    private int RewardSelector()
    {
        randomReward = Random.Range(0, rewards.Length);

        return randomReward;
    }

    private int PointerRandomDirection()
    {
        int pRandomDir = plastRandomDir;

        if (pointerDir.Length <= 1)
            return 0;

        while (pRandomDir == plastRandomDir)
        {
            pRandomDir = Random.Range(0, pointerDir.Length);
        }

        plastRandomDir = pRandomDir;
        return pRandomDir;
    }

    private int RingRandomDirection()
    {
        int rRandomDir = rlastRandomDir;

        if (ringDir.Length <= 1)
            return 0;

        while (rRandomDir == rlastRandomDir)
        {
            rRandomDir = Random.Range(0, ringDir.Length);
        }

        rlastRandomDir = rRandomDir;
        return rRandomDir;
    }

    public void OnSpinButtonClick()
    {
        if(spinIsEnabled == false && isSpinning == false)
            spinIsEnabled = true;

        spinWheelCanvas.interactable = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Debug.Log`...You need this in Unity. Put many of them in the coroutine function and in the `if` statements in the `Update` function. This can help you track down the problem.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks for the reply. That is exactly what I've been doing so far. The problem is that every thing checks out. I tried debugging the Transforms, the floats and the loops. All the logs print as they should until it stops. Then I check the angles (the only thing that could affect the break condition) and they're fine as well.

Comment: Is the infinite loop 'for(;;)' required in the Spin() method? Have you tried yielding each time your time increments?

Comment: @ClassyBear Yes I did, it's crucial for Quaternion.RotateTowards(). Without the for(;;) loop it would only run for one frame. What the for loop does is run that function until it reaches the if statement and break the loop for one **time**

Comment: When you add `Debug.Log` like I mentioned you will see the last place it get's stuck then tell us where that place is. Few questions: What do you mean by "stuck". The editor/programs freezes? 2.I noticed there is a `break;` in the `for` loop. Are you trying to break out of that `for` loop, the `while` loop or the `Spin` function?

Comment: @Programmer I understood what you meant, but as I said in the question, it stops randomly so there is no specific place that I could tell you about. And what I by "stuck" is that is that the spinning animation stops. The rest of the game runs smoothly. See the animation has to spin towards a randomly chosen spot for **15 times**. The break function is actually for the `for` loop. Once it breaks from the for loop it will finish the rest of the `while` loop by retuning null, and it will continue on doing this 15 times until it meets the `while` loop condition and it will exit the coroutine.

Comment: I can't believe I have to say this again.  Put `Debug.Log(in a while loop)"` inside the while loop in the  coroutine function. Put `Debug.Log(in a for loop)"` in the `for (;;)`.  Put others in the `if` statement. Run it! When it is "stuck" check the last debug and tell us what is the last Debug. Make it easier for people to help since they don't have your scene and therefore cannot replicate your problem.

Comment: @Programmer I did what you said and I placed a `Debug.Log()` before the `if` statement, after the `if` statement and in the while loop. The last Log that was printed is the one before the `if` statement, which means that it didn't meet the condition?

Comment: Yup. You see how easy that is? Note that there are 3 `if` statements. I don't know which one it is so you may need to modify your question with code that includes the log then show us the last log. I can then tell tell why that's happening but it's likely the condition stuff you mentioned

Comment: @Programmer I just updated it, it's the `if` with the `break;`.

Comment: I actually said to put debug in the if statement in the update function. And also in the coroutine function. I don't think this is working about.There is also problem in the way you generate random number. How about this: explain to me what exactly you are doing and when to spin whatever it is. I will have to re-write the code if I clearly understand it.

Comment: its probably just that the rotations never are perfectly equal due to floating point shenanigans. maybe try `Mathf.Approximately(float, float)` instead https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find the answer using your existing solution, here is an alternative solution you might appreciate, which arguably is more simple.

A simpler way to achieve the spinning effect and stopping at random angles:
Make 2 animations (In the Animation/Animator windows), a 0-180 degree animation and a 180-360 degree animation, then have them transition between each other.

Making just one 0-360 animation will most likely look buggy, hence I advise to make it in 2 parts.

You can then decide the speed of this animation by adjusting the animation speed and Animator parameters (which control what animations are playing) through code.

To have the spinning wheel stop at random angles you could have a float value in the animator called "Speed", the higher the speed the longer time it takes to stop the animation, hence random stopping angles are achieved.

When the speed hits 0, set the animation speed to 0 as well, that should stop the animation at the designated angle.

Feel free to ask questions if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. it seems like an interesting suggestion. I will give it a try if my code didn't work at all. Thank you.